# Calculating the number of iterations in a variable number of nested for-loops

Tags: summation, programming

My goal is to calculate the number of iterations made in a variable number of `for`-loops following this structure:

```
for(i = 0; i <= x; i++)
  for(j = 0; j <= i + 1; j++)
    for(k = 0; k <= j + 1; k++)
      ...
        for(n = 0; n <= (n - 1) + 1; n++)
```

For example, how many iterations will be made when x = 10 with 5 loops?

To try forming an equation for this problem, I searched for a pattern by simplifying summations. Here are my results:

One `for`-loop:

- Summation: $$\sum_{i=0}^x 1$$
- Simplified: $$x+1$$

Two `for`-loops:

- Summation: $$\sum_{i=0}^x \sum_{j=0}^{i+1} 1$$
- Simplified: $$\frac{x^2+5x+4}{2}$$

Three `for`-loops:

- Summation: $$\sum_{i=0}^x \sum_{j=0}^{i+1} \sum_{k=0}^{j+1} 1$$
- Simplified: $$\frac{x^3+12x^2+41x+30}{6}$$

The only patterns that I see are:

- The denominator could be represented as $n!$
- The numerator is a polynomial of degree $n$

How can I represent a variable number of these nested loops as an equation?

Comment: Very interesting math behind the given answers. From a pure complexity analysis of algorithms, isn't it sufficient to remember that $p$ nested for-loops have a complexity growing as $\Theta(n^p) $? However, congrats on high quality answers the question sparked off.

Comment: @G.Fougeron I suppose, but I was more interested in the idea of taking this programming concept into mathematics, and how I would express it as an equation. More of a curiosity thing than anything else. :) I felt like it was possible but I couldn't figure out the solution on my own. The quality of the answers here blew me away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the problem with $p$ summations and counting as you did the formulae are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  p & S_p \\
 1 & (x+1) \\
 2 & \frac{1}{2} (x+1) (x+4) \\
 3 & \frac{1}{6} (x+1) (x+5) (x+6) \\
 4 & \frac{1}{24} (x+1) (x+6) (x+7) (x+8) \\
 5 & \frac{1}{120} (x+1) (x+7) (x+8) (x+9) (x+10) \\
 6 & \frac{1}{720} (x+1) (x+8) (x+9) (x+10) (x+11) (x+12)
\end{array}
\right)$$ from which seems to appear the general pattern

$$\color{red}{S_p=\frac 1{p!}(x+1)\prod_{i=p+2}^{2p}(x+i)}$$ Using Pochhammer symbols $$S_p=\frac{(x+1) }{p!}(x+p+2)_{p-1}$$ You also could use $$\frac{S_{p+1}}{S_p}=\frac{(x+2 p+1) (x+2 p+2)}{(p+1) (x+p+2)}$$  For $p=5$ and $x=10$, this would give $10659$.

Comment: Wow, incredible. Thank you so much!! This is very cool.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge. You are very welcome ! I did not prove anything. I just did the same as you did but I was looking for the factors and then I just observed.

Comment: I'm only in Calculus 2 and we were just introduced to series, so I'm trying to apply what I'm learning to my computer science studies. I was unaware of the pi-product symbol, which I learned from your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: You have $\Pi_{i=1}^n$ in the same way as  $\Sigma_{i=1}^n$ for the sum

Answer (score 3):

**Main Solution**

Using notation for [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), let 
$$\begin{align}
f(x)\quad\;
&=\frac {x+1}{(p+1)!}(x+mp+m)^\underline{p}\\
&=\frac {x+1}{(p+1)!}(x+mp+m-1)^\underline{p-1}(x+mp+m)\\
\Rightarrow\quad 
f(x-1)
&=\frac x{(p+1)!} (x-1+mp+m)^\underline{p}\\
&=\frac x{(p+1)!}(x+mp+m-p)(x+mp+m-1)^\underline{p-1}\\
\text{Subtracting,}\hspace{3.5cm}\\
f(x)-f(x-1)
&=\frac {(x+mp+m-1)^\underline{p-1}}{(p+1)!}\big[(x+1)\ (x+mp+m)-x\ (x+mp+m-p)\big]\\
&=\frac {(x+mp+m-1)^\underline{p-1}}{(p+1)!}\big[(x+m)(p+1)\big]\\
&=\frac {(x+m)}{p!} \big(x+mp+m-1\big)^\underline{p-1} \\
&=\bigg\langle {x,p\atop p}\bigg\rangle_m \hspace{5cm}\text{(assigned notation)}\\
\text{Summing by telescoping gives}\hspace{0cm}\\
\sum_{x=0}^{y+m-1}\bigg\langle {x,p\atop p}\bigg\rangle_m
&=f(y+m-1)\\
&=\frac {(y+m)}{(p+1)!}\big(y+mp+2m-1\big)^\underline{p}\\
&=\frac {(y+m)}{(p+1)!}\big(y+m(p+1)+m-1\big)^\underline{p}\\
&=\bigg\langle {y,p+1\atop p+1}\bigg\rangle_m \hspace{6cm}\cdots (1)\\
\end{align}$$

For  $m=2$,

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\bigg\langle {x,p\atop p}\bigg\rangle_2
&&=\bigg\langle {y,p+1\atop p+1}\bigg\rangle_2\\
\text{i.e.}\qquad\qquad &\sum_{x=0}^{(y+1)}\frac {x+2}{p!}(x+2p+1)^{\underline{p-1}}
&&=\frac {(y+2)}{(p+1)!}(y+2p+3)^\underline{p}\\
p=1:\;\;
&\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}(x+2)
&&=\frac 12(y+2)(y+5)&\\
p=2:\;\;
&\sum_{r=0}^{y=1}\frac 12(x+2)(x+5)
&&=\frac 16(y+2)(y+6)(y+7)&\\
p=3:\;\;
&\sum_{r=0}^{y=1}\frac 16(x+2)(x+6)(x+7)
&&=\frac 1{24}(y+2)(y+7)(y+8)(y+9)&
\\
\end{align}$$

(*) The angle bracket coefficient notation facilitates the cascading of summation, e.g.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\sum_{i=0}^{x+1}\sum_{j=0}^{i+1}\sum_{k=0}^{j+1}1
&=\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\sum_{i=0}^{x+1}\sum_{j=0}^{i+1}\bigg\langle {j,1\atop 1}\bigg\rangle_2\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\sum_{i=0}^{x+1}\bigg\langle {i,2\atop 2}\bigg\rangle_2\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\bigg\langle {x,3\atop 3}\bigg\rangle_2\\
&=\bigg\langle {y,4\atop 4}\bigg\rangle_2\\
&=\frac 1{24}(y+2)(y+7)(x+8)(x+9)
\end{align}$$

NB - for the outermost summation, if the upper limit is $y$, then the answer is $\frac 1{24}(y+1)(y+6)(y+7)(y+8)$.

---

**Relationship with Binomial Coefficients**

The above may also be represented using binomial coefficients, e.g.

$$\bigg\langle {x,p\atop p}\bigg\rangle_m=\frac {(x+m)}p\binom {x+mp+m-1}{p-1}$$

When $m=1$, the angle-bracket coefficient reduces to a binomial coefficent

$$\bigg\langle {x,p\atop p}\bigg\rangle_1=\binom {x+p}p$$
thus equation ($1$) reduces to the familiar
$$\sum_{x=0}^y\binom {x+p}p=\binom{y+p+1}{p+1}$$

---

**Addendum**

A friend who is an excellent mathematician pointed out, with a neat combinatorial proof, that the final solution for (*) can be expressed as 
$$\binom {y+2p+2}{p+1}-\binom {y+2p+2}{p-1}$$

Using this insight we can actually derive that solution more directly for the case where $m=2$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\bigg\langle {x,p\atop p}\bigg\rangle_2
&=\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\frac{x+2}p\binom {x+2p+1}{p-1}\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\binom {x+2p}p-\binom {x+2p}{p-2}\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{y+1}\left[\binom {x+2p+1}{p+1}-\binom {x+2p}{p+1}\right]-\left[\binom {x+2p+1}{p-1}-\binom {x+2p}{p-1}\right]\\
&=\left[\binom {y+2p+2}{p+1}-\binom {2p}{p+1}\right]-\left[\binom {y+2p+2}{p-1}-\binom {2p}{p-1}\right]\\
&=\binom{y+2p+2}{p+1}-\binom {y+2p+2}{p-1}
\qquad\qquad\scriptsize\text{as }\binom {2p}{p+1}=\binom {2p}{p-1}\\
&=\frac {y+2}{p+1}\binom {y+\overline{2p+1}+1}p\\
&=\bigg\langle {y,p+1\atop p+1}\bigg\rangle_2
\end{align}$$
which allows us to go to (*) directly.

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: @G.Fougeron - Thank you! Very kind of you :)

Comment: http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/2011/09/mind_blown.gif 

Most of this was completely above my calc 2 head, but I appreciate your extremely detailed response. I hope one day to be able to understand this all ._.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge You're welcome! It was interesting to discover this new summation identity as a result of answering your question. The result for $m=1$ is well-known but it is nice to know that a neat closed form exists for the general case.